# Fluent NHibernate, HasManytoMany and Primary Key issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I think this should be straightforward, but with NHibernate simple things are always the most complicated.

I have two POCOs which reference each other through HasManyToMany:

```
public class Foo1
{
//other properties
public virtual IList<Foo2> Foo2s {get;set;}
}
public class Foo2
{
//other properties
public virtual IList<Foo1> Foo1s {get;set;}
}
```

And the mappings:

```
class Foo1Map : ClassMap<Foo1>
{
//other mappings
HasManyToMany(c => c.Foo2s);
}
class Foo2Map : ClassMap<Foo2>
{
//other mappings
HasManyToMany(c => c.Foo1s);
}
```

The join table is correctly created, it has 2 fields which are on foreign keys to the respective tables, all fine, the HUGE problem is that those 2 fields should be primary key (or at least unique) while they aren't. I tried playing around with various fluent methods chained to HasManyToMany but without any result.

How do I get the generated manytomany table to have primary key on the 2 foreign key fields without having to create a custom POCO and map it with composite key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a unique constraint and also index

```
class Foo1Map : ClassMap<Foo1>
{
    //other mappings
    HasManyToMany(c => c.Foo2s)
        .ParentKeyColumns.Add("foo1_id", p => p.UniqueKey("unique_constraint1").Index("someIndex"))
        .ChildKeyColumns.Add("foo2_id", p => p.UniqueKey("unique_constraint1"));
}
```

Updated: or as a convention for HasMany (code like this i used in a project), not nice but working

```
public class IndexOneToManyColumnsConvention : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        var mappingfield = instance.Key.Columns.First().GetType()
            .GetField("mapping", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        var columnMapping = (ColumnMapping)mappingfield.GetValue(instance.Key.Columns.First());

        if (!columnMapping.HasValue(c => c.Index))
        {
            var typename = instance.Member.DeclaringType.Name;

            columnMapping.Index = string.Format("index_{0}_{1}",
                typename.ToLower(), instance.Member.Name.ToLower());
        }
    }
}
```

i think there is the code in the trunk of FNH to get rid of this hack

Comment: Any idea if this has since been dealt with in a saner way in the three years since? Otherwise, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Ted I dont'know. But i doubt it wil be there soon if not present because the project is in maintenance mode since NHibernate introduced MappingByCode.

Answer (score 1):

I have been running into the limitations of fluent and have given up on setting up more advanced schema tweaks using it. I had some headaches setting up index's on lookup tables so just added the SQL to a post creation script.

We have database project which creates the database using NHibernate then runs a set up post creation scripts which create index's and the stored procedures we use.

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but I was struggling with this issue yesterday so thought I'd share my solution and a bit of code to give you a head start if this is the route you decide to head down.

Be interesting to see what other have done here!

```
private void ExecuteScripts(string dir, bool useTransaction = true, bool useMasterConnection = false)
{
    foreach (var file in SqlFiles.Where(x => x.Contains(dir)))
    {
        var resource = file.Substring((Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".scripts.").Length);               

        if (useTransaction)
            ExecuteSqlWithTransaction(resource, useMasterConnection);
        else
            ExecuteSqlWithoutTransaction(resource, useMasterConnection);
    }
}



 private void ExecuteSqlWithoutTransaction(string sqlFile, bool useMasterConnection = false)
        {
            var sql = string.Empty;

            var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream((Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".scripts.") + sqlFile.Replace('\\', '.'));

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                sql = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            // replace the [[[dbName]]] and [[[SQLDATAFILEPATH]]] with ACTUAL DB settings we want to work with
            sql = sql.Replace("[[[DBNAME]]]", DbName);
            sql = sql.Replace("[[[SQLDATAFILEPATH]]]", SqlDataFilePath);

            var regex = new Regex("^GO", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
            var lines = regex.Split(sql);

            var currentConnection = (useMasterConnection) ? MasterSqlConnection : SqlConnection;

            using (var cmd = currentConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = currentConnection;

                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    if (line.Length > 0)
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = line;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        try
                        {
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {
                            //ShowInfo("Error running script " + sqlFile + "    Error: " + ex.Message);
                            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ArticleProjectAssignments] ADD  CONSTRAINT [pk_ArticleProjectAssignments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ArticleId] ASC,
    [ProjectId] ASC
)
GO
```

Comment: It surely is a workaround worth of notice. I don't have time/resources to try it out, and usually I don't use NHibernate, was forced on this project to use it, else I'm all EF Code First 4.1 which is so much more advanced, easier to use, etc. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MatteoMosca out of interest, does create EF the primary keys on its own or how do you tell it to do it?

Comment: EF automatically puts the primary key on autogenerated many-to-many tables, like my example. I think it's the right thing, there's no reason the primary key shouldn't be on the only 2 fields of a many-to-many table. Different thing for a table that is "many-to-many" but has other fields, in that case you have a POCO mapped to it, etc.